# Upgraded python has no packages and no pip / easy install

Tags: upgrade, package-management, software-installation, python, pip

I managed to upgrade python from `2.7.3` to `2.7.9` (to get SNI support) by compiling it from source, but it wouldn't install unless I removed `/usr/local/lib/python2.7`.
(I kept a copy of the old one in `/tmp`).

Python works, but has no packages. For example:

```
~$ pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
from pip import main
ImportError: No module named pip
```

or in the interpreter:

```
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PIL
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named PIL
```

Is there a way to get PIP working again so I can install packages or can I somehow use the old packages I saved to `/tmp/python2.7`.

Comment: 1) A manual build of python requires also a manual build of pip ( pip-9.0.1.tar.gz ) https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip ... 2) /tmp/ is not supposed to be used ( for anything ) : The default /tmp/ permissions will change.  .... /home/[user-name]/tmp/ can be used.

Comment: So @KnudLarsen - I couldn't build a new PIP but your comment made me realize my issue is that PIP does run if i run it from :/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages - but from any other directory it does not , which means I think - it's an environmental variable thats off?

Comment: ?How about a link to e.g. `/home/[name]/` *pip* .... Or wherever else you are using `pip` .  Might work.